# Problems with a for loop using writeRaster

Tags: r, for-loop

I am trying to create a for loop to merge 4 raster (EVI MODIS tiles) at a time (because the 4 raster create one big map) in a list of 8 raster (my real list is much more bigger but I am doing a test), then crop the whole map and finally write (writeRaster) the result in the same folder. This is the code I am using but I dont know if I am doing the for loop correctly:

```
library(raster)
library(gdalUtils)    
library(rgdal)
library("RStoolbox")

setwd("D:/MODIS/Tesis/Ecuador_2000-2019/HDF-Terra/EVI_terra/New folder/New folder")
files <- list.files(pattern=".tif$",full.names = FALSE)
vector <- c(files[1:4], files[5:8])
for (i in vector)
{
 x <- files
x1 <- (raster(x[1])/10000) # we create a raster for each object in the vector "x" (files) to merge them
x2 <- (raster(x[2])/10000)
x3 <- (raster(x[3])/10000)
x4 <- (raster(x[4])/10000)
enlist <- list(x1,x2,x3,x4)
y <- do.call(merge, enlist)
cropped <- crop(y, size) # we crop the new full map (4 tiles) with the object "size" (polygon)
writeRaster(cropped, filename = paste0("EVI_crop_", x)) # we extract the new tif
```

I have to say that the first raster is created correctly but an error appears for the second:

> Error in .rasterObjectFromFile(x, band = band, objecttype =
> "RasterLayer",  :    Cannot create a RasterLayer object from this
> file. In addition: There were 35 warnings (use warnings() to see them)
>
> warnings() Warning messages:  1: In if (filename == "") { ... :   the
> condition has length > 1 and only the first element will be used  2:
> In if (!file.exists(dirname(filename))) { ... :   the condition has
>
> > length > 1 and only the first element will be used  3: In if (nchar(ext) < 3) { ... :   the condition has length > 1 and only the
> > first element will be used  4: In if (ext == ".tif" | ext == ".tiff") {... :   the condition has length > 1 and only the first
> > element will be used  5: In if (filename == "") { ... :    the
> > condition has length > 1 and only the first element will be used  6:
> > In if (file.exists(filename)) { ... :    the condition has length > 1
> > and
> > only the first element will be used  7: In if (nchar(filename) == 0) stop("empty file name") : the condition has length > 1 and only the
> > first element will be used  8: In if (x == "" | x == ".") { ... :
> > the condition has length > 1 and only the first element will be used
> > 9: In if (!start %in% c("htt", "ftp")) { ... :   the condition has
> > length > 1 and only the first element will be used  10: In if (fileext
> > %in% c(".GRD", ".GRI")) { ... :   the condition has length > 1 and
> > only the first element will be used  11: In if (!file.exists(x)) { ...
> > :   the condition has length > 1 and only the first element will be
> > used  12: In if ((fileext %in% c(".HE5", ".NC", ".NCF", ".NC4",  ... :
> > the condition has length > 1 and only the first element will be used
> > 13: In if (fileext == ".GRD") { ... :   the condition has length > 1
> > and only the first element will be used  14: In if (fileext %in%
> > c(".BIN")) { ... :   the condition has length > 1 and only the first
> > element will be used  15: In if (fileext == ".DOC") { ... :   the
> > condition has length > 1 and only the first element will be used  16:
> > In if (fileext %in% c(".SGRD", ".SDAT")) { ... :   the condition has
> > length > 1 and only the first element will be used  17: In if
> > (nchar(filename) == 0) stop("empty file name") :   the condition has
> > length > 1 and only the first element will be used  18: In if
> > (file.exists(file)) { ... :   the condition has length > 1 and only
> > the first element will be used  19: In
> > normalizePath(path.expand(path), winslash, mustWork) :
> > path[2]="D:/MODIS/Tesis/Ecuador_2000-2019/HDF-Terra/EVI_terra/New
> > folder/New
> > folder/EVI_crop_MOD13Q1.A2000065.h09v09.006.2015136022455.tif": The
> > system cannot find the file specified  20: In
> > normalizePath(path.expand(path), winslash, mustWork) :
> > path[3]="D:/MODIS/Tesis/Ecuador_2000-2019/HDF-Terra/EVI_terra/New
> > folder/New
> > folder/EVI_crop_MOD13Q1.A2000065.h10v08.006.2015136022544.tif": The
> > system cannot find the file specified  21: In
> > normalizePath(path.expand(path), winslash, mustWork) :
> > path[4]="D:/MODIS/Tesis/Ecuador_2000-2019/HDF-Terra/EVI_terra/New
> > folder/New
> > folder/EVI_crop_MOD13Q1.A2000065.h10v09.006.2015136022526.tif": The
> > system cannot find the file specified  22: In
> > normalizePath(path.expand(path), winslash, mustWork) :
> > path[5]="D:/MODIS/Tesis/Ecuador_2000-2019/HDF-Terra/EVI_terra/New
> > folder/New
> > folder/EVI_crop_MOD13Q1.A2000081.h09v08.006.2015136040620.tif": The
> > system cannot find the file specified  23: In
> > normalizePath(path.expand(path), winslash, mustWork) :
> > path[6]="D:/MODIS/Tesis/Ecuador_2000-2019/HDF-Terra/EVI_terra/New
> > folder/New
> > folder/EVI_crop_MOD13Q1.A2000081.h09v09.006.2015136040620.tif": The
> > system cannot find the file specified  24: In
> > normalizePath(path.expand(path), winslash, mustWork) :
> > path[7]="D:/MODIS/Tesis/Ecuador_2000-2019/HDF-Terra/EVI_terra/New
> > folder/New
> > folder/EVI_crop_MOD13Q1.A2000081.h10v08.006.2015136040049.tif": The
> > system cannot find the file specified  25: In
> > normalizePath(path.expand(path), winslash, mustWork) :
> > path[8]="D:/MODIS/Tesis/Ecuador_2000-2019/HDF-Terra/EVI_terra/New
> > folder/New
> > folder/EVI_crop_MOD13Q1.A2000081.h10v09.006.2015136040705.tif": The
> > system cannot find the file specified  26: In if (nchar(filename) ==
> > 0) stop("empty file name") :   the condition has length > 1 and only
> > the first element will be used  27: In if (file.exists(file)) { ... :
> > the condition has length > 1 and only the first element will be used
> > 28: In normalizePath(path.expand(path), winslash, mustWork) :
> > path[2]="D:/MODIS/Tesis/Ecuador_2000-2019/HDF-Terra/EVI_terra/New
> > folder/New
> > folder/EVI_crop_MOD13Q1.A2000065.h09v09.006.2015136022455.tif": The
> > system cannot find the file specified  29: In
> > normalizePath(path.expand(path), winslash, mustWork) :
> > path[3]="D:/MODIS/Tesis/Ecuador_2000-2019/HDF-Terra/EVI_terra/New
> > folder/New
> > folder/EVI_crop_MOD13Q1.A2000065.h10v08.006.2015136022544.tif": The
> > system cannot find the file specified  30: In
> > normalizePath(path.expand(path), winslash, mustWork) :
> > path[4]="D:/MODIS/Tesis/Ecuador_2000-2019/HDF-Terra/EVI_terra/New
> > folder/New
> > folder/EVI_crop_MOD13Q1.A2000065.h10v09.006.2015136022526.tif": The
> > system cannot find the file specified  31: In
> > normalizePath(path.expand(path), winslash, mustWork) :
> > path[5]="D:/MODIS/Tesis/Ecuador_2000-2019/HDF-Terra/EVI_terra/New
> > folder/New
> > folder/EVI_crop_MOD13Q1.A2000081.h09v08.006.2015136040620.tif": The
> > system cannot find the file specified  32: In
> > normalizePath(path.expand(path), winslash, mustWork) :
> > path[6]="D:/MODIS/Tesis/Ecuador_2000-2019/HDF-Terra/EVI_terra/New
> > folder/New
> > folder/EVI_crop_MOD13Q1.A2000081.h09v09.006.2015136040620.tif": The
> > system cannot find the file specified  33: In
> > normalizePath(path.expand(path), winslash, mustWork) :
> > path[7]="D:/MODIS/Tesis/Ecuador_2000-2019/HDF-Terra/EVI_terra/New
> > folder/New
> > folder/EVI_crop_MOD13Q1.A2000081.h10v08.006.2015136040049.tif": The
> > system cannot find the file specified  34: In
> > normalizePath(path.expand(path), winslash, mustWork) :
> > path[8]="D:/MODIS/Tesis/Ecuador_2000-2019/HDF-Terra/EVI_terra/New
> > folder/New
> > folder/EVI_crop_MOD13Q1.A2000081.h10v09.006.2015136040705.tif": The
> > system cannot find the file specified  35: In if (!file.exists(x)) {
> > ... :   the condition has length > 1 and only the first element will
> > be used

I am new in R but understand for loops had been the most difficult for me.
Thanks

Comment: Which package is the function `raster()` from? please add this to your post. Also it seems the object type is wrong, are you sure ".tif" files are of "RasterLayer" types? Have you tried `warning()` as suggested?

Comment: Sorry for the long post, I added the packages I used and the warnings messages (as I said before, I am a beginner using R so I hardly understand some of them). And, I already manipulated the original files (.tif) in QGIS, and then imported them in R with "raster" function, so I suppose they are raster files.

Comment: Instead of using: 'enlist <- list(x1,x2,x3,x4)', 'y <- do.call(merge, enlist)', just merge directly: assign(x, merge(x1,x2,x3,x4).